# Fail to push to Heroku: /app/.heroku/python/bin/pip:No such file or directory

Tags: django, heroku

I am trying to push a Django project to Heroku, but it keeps telling me that the following:

```
/app/.heroku/python/bin/pip: No such file or directory
```

The complete error message is shown below. How can I address this issue? Do I need to first install pip on Heroku?

```
Counting objects: 451, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (383/383), done.
Writing objects: 100% (451/451), 1.07 MiB | 349.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 451 (delta 87), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote: -----> Installing python-3.5.1
remote: -----> Installing pip
remote: -----> Installing requirements with pip
remote:        /app/tmp/buildpacks/779a8bbfbbe7e1b715476c0b23fc63a2103b3e4131eda558669aba8fb5e6e05682419376144189b29beb5dee6d7626b4d3385edb0954bffea6c67d8cf622fd51
/bin/steps/pip-install: line 5: /app/.heroku/python/bin/pip: No such file or directory
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !   Push rejected to rocky-tor-70537.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/rocky-tor-70537.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/rocky-tor-70537.git'
```

My requirements.txt file is empty, as shown below.

```
# this is for Heroku and other servers.
# Locally, you should install requirements_base.txt
-r requirements_server.txt
```

My requirements_server.txt is as follows:

```
-r requirements_base.txt
# packages that are unnecessary on Windows/Mac local dev environments, or don't install properly
psycopg2>=2.5.1
```

My requirements_base.txt is as follows:

```
appdirs==1.4.3
asgi-redis==0.14.1
asgiref==0.14.0
autobahn==0.16.0
Babel==2.3.4
boto==2.42.0
channels==0.17.3
colorama==0.3.7
contextlib2==0.5.4
coverage==4.2
daphne==0.14.3
dj-database-url==0.4.1
Django==1.8.8
django-countries==4.0
django-easymoney==0.7.1
django-floppyforms==1.7.0
django-idmap==0.4.1
django-vanilla-views==1.0.4
djangorestframework==3.4.6
honcho==0.7.1
huey==1.2.0
IPy==0.83
mock==2.0.0
msgpack-python==0.4.8
otree-core==1.2.8
otree-save-the-change==1.1.3
packaging==16.8
pbr==1.10.0
py==1.4.31
pyparsing==2.2.0
pytest==2.9.2
pytest-django==3.0.0
python-redis-lock==3.2.0
pytz==2016.6.1
raven==5.25.0
redis==2.10.5
requests==2.11.1
schema==0.6.2
six==1.10.0
Twisted==16.2.0
txaio==2.5.1
unicodecsv==0.14.1
whitenoise==3.2.1
ws4py==0.3.5
XlsxWriter==0.9.3
zope.interface==4.2.0
```

Comment: Hi, were you able to fix this issue? I having the same trouble on windows

Answer (score 14):

I ran into this issue recently and was able to adjust it by changing the python version in the runtime.txt.

Changing to

```
python-3.5.2
```

But based off your requirements that you have listed, it seems like you are never getting to the requirements_base.txt.

In your requirements_server.txt file, change it so that:

```
-r requirements_base.txt
```

is listed there.

Comment: For some reason it does not work for me. Still receiving the same error message. I don't know why it still tries to install python-3.5.1 when I change the runtime.txt to other versions of python (I tried 3.6.1 and 3.5.2). Is there anywhere else to specify the version of python used?

Comment: Can you post the requirements.txt file?

Comment: Edited comment to reflect issues with requirements.txt file

Comment: Sorry that I mistakenly typed requirements_server where it should be requirements_base. So I actually had the above line in my requirements_server.txt file.

Comment: uses python-3.5.1 and face this issue. But somehow python3.5.2 work perfectly.

Comment: I was getting the same issue with python 3.4.2 and changing it to 3.5.2 worked for me. It is interesting that the application I was uploading worked before and was untouched for a complete year so I just tried the `git push heroku master` to a different heroku app (only difference is time) and failed with this issue.

Answer (score 6):

I simply had two typos in my `runtime.txt`

Make sure it says `python-3.6.1` and not `Python-3.6.1` or `python 3.6.1`

The error message is pretty bad. May this post save someone 30 minutes.

Comment: Thanks! Had `python 2.7.13` but needed `python-2.7.13`. Stupid that it will continue normally if you're missing the `-` until it tries to use `pip`.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like Heroku now supports **only** `3.6.1` and `2.7.13` Python versions.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes#supported-python-runtimes

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the default heroku buildpack I would guess that the requirements.txt file in your project folder is missing.

Comment: I have the requirements.txt.

Comment: Do you use some custom buildpack? Can you try `heroku config:unset BUILDPACK_URL` and push your code again

Comment: How to check the buildpack? I used the above command, still receiving the same error messages.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on Ubuntu 16.04 and after manually installing Heroku CLI, using

```
wget https://cli-assets.heroku.com/branches/stable/heroku-REPLACE_ME_OS-REPLACE_ME_ARCH.tar.gz -O heroku.tar.gz

mkdir -p /usr/local/lib

tar -xvzf heroku.tar.gz -C /usr/local/lib

/usr/local/lib/heroku/install
```

it worked like a charm.

In the folder I have 4 files. One is python script, second is procfile (no extension) with content `web: gunicorn skripta1:app`. Third is requirements.txt with:

```
appdirs==1.4.3
bokeh==0.12.5
click==6.7
Flask==0.12.2
gunicorn==19.7.1
itsdangerous==0.24
Jinja2==2.9.6
MarkupSafe==1.0
numpy==1.12.1
packaging==16.8
pandas==0.20.1
pandas-datareader==0.4.0
pyparsing==2.2.0
python-dateutil==2.6.0
pytz==2017.2
PyYAML==3.12
requests==2.14.2
requests-file==1.4.2
requests-ftp==0.3.1
six==1.10.0
tornado==4.5.1
Werkzeug==0.12.2
```

And fourth is runtime.txt with `python-3.5.2`

Answer (score 0):

According to Heroku documentation, the only two officially supported python runtimes are 2.7.13, and 3.6.1.
I recently had the same issue with oTree deployment in heroku, but as soon as I changed `runtime.txt` to `python-3.6.1` everything went smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

Oh dear - I removed a blank line in my `requirements/production.txt` in order to try and change the line number and everything started working (or rather on to my next completely different error)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same problem on Windows trying to deploy a Python app to Heroku.  Turns out it was a file encoding problem.  Depending on how you create Procfile, requirements.txt and runtime.txt your encoding may vary.

Assuming you're running Windows, use PowerShell.  Get the following [PowerShell Function](https://gist.github.com/zommarin/1480974) and paste it in to your PowerShell console.  Using this, you can check your file encoding:

`get-fileencoding requirements.txt`

If it comes back anything besides ascii that's probably the issue.  In my case, my three files were all unicode.  I just did this to force them to ASCII:

`'python-3.6.1' | out-file -en ascii runtime.txt`

You can also use an editor and then save the file using ASCII encoding.

Once I made this change to my Procfile, requirements.txt and runtime.txt I was able to successfully deploy to Heroku.

Answer (score 0):

I was switching from app engine to heroku and had a *setup.cfg* file in the root directory with following content:

```
[install]
prefix=
```

It caused this issues while deployment. After removing everything went well.