# /app/.heroku/python/bin/pip: No such file or directory Python Flask Heroku Deployment failing

Tags: heroku, flask

I am trying to deploy a Flask application on Heroku and I am getting this error when I run:

```
git push heroku master
```

Error:

```
Installing requirements with pip
/app/tmp/buildpacks/779a8bbfbbe7e1b715476c0b23fc63a2103b3e4131eda558669aba8fb5e6e05682419376144189b29beb5dee6d7626b4d3385edb0954bffea6c67d8cf622fd51/bin/steps/pip-install: line 7: /app/.heroku/python/bin/pip: No such file or directory
! Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
! Push failed
```

I have specified python-2.7.13 in runtime.txt.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

A friend of mine encountered this issue lately he fixed by changing the python version in the runtime.txt.

So based on his solution: Try to change the python version in the runtime.txt to `python-3.5.2`

Update: [Found this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44032490/fail-to-push-to-heroku-app-heroku-python-bin-pipno-such-file-or-directory), user3821012 has ran into same issue most up voted answer has suggested same solution. You gotta give it a try.